# Any Good Opensource Analytics front end tool?

Tags: hadoop, hive, web-analytics-tools

Is there any good open source web-based front end analytics tool that can talk to HIVE/HDFS for data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two that I recently became aware of are:
http://www.jaspersoft.com/
http://datameer.com/products/das-for-hadoop-users.html

I don't have a lot of info on these yet, have just begun researching them, but... It's two I'm aware of and wanted to share.

UPDATE:
I found out about [Snowfinch](http://blog.kiskolabs.com/post/5794285908/introducing-snowfinch-open-source-realtime-web) and wanted to include it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Beeswax from Cloudera'a HUE
http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/07/whats-new-in-cdh3b2-hue/
http://www.slideshare.net/cwsteinbach/cloudera-huebeeswax

This is probably what you are looking for.